# Automating Correlation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, parameter-passing, correlation

My scripts have lot of dynamically changing variables for which I need to use correlation (regular expression / xpath extractor)  Is there any way with which we can automate or minimize this and with which JMeter can identify the variables and auto find and replace it.
Your suggestion would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the test development shell of OctoPerf?  At least for me it takes an enormous amount of pain out of Jmeter test code development.

And no, I don't work for them....

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using [3rd party recording service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FFDYaEqqxY) in **SmartJMX** mode which performs automatic correlation of any dynamic parameters including timestamps, usernames, etc.

See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for more details.